# AE.Net.Mail Imap Library Always returns NULL for Body

Tags: c#, .net, email, imap

I am using AE.Net.Mail to write a small mail client. I have used this library in the past without any issues. However, this time around I am unable to retrieve the Body content of mail.

Below is my code:

```
using (var imap = new AE.Net.Mail.ImapClient("imap-mail..com", "", "", AE.Net.Mail.AuthMethods.Login, 993, true))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < messageCount; i++)
    {
        messages.Add(imap.GetMessage(i, false, false));
        worker.ReportProgress(i);
    }
}
```

where `messages` is a `List` of type `MailMessage`. The problem I am having is that I can successfully get the Headers for each email in my Inbox but I can *never* get the Body for that email.

What I do is, I get all the Mail Headers and put 'em in a list. Then when I click on a list item, I then download the corresponding Body and display it. But I can't do it because the Body is always `null`. Why does Body always return `null`? I've seen this same question asked so mnay times for this library but the answers so far haven't been of any help because their solutions are related to the fact that they used `headersOnly: true` (which means it will only download headers). But I don't do that, I only download the headers first then later on when I need the Body, I use headersOnly: false so I don't see why it's returning null?

Comment: AE.Net.Mail is really buggy, you'll probably have better luck with [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit).

Comment: @jstedfast Thanks. I'll stick with MailKit. AEM's also too slow in downloading mail.

Comment: FWIW, it seems this might be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242600/ae-net-mail-message-value-is-null/21358544#21358544

Comment: @jstedfast could it just be that its trying to get body wiyh incorrect encoding and thats whycit returns null?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if that's the case, pretty much none of the IMAP or POP3 libraries out there properly handle charset encodings (except MailKit and MimeKit, of course).